# Series in hyperbolic sines.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I was looking into a problem and I arrived to something in which I want to expand some function $\varphi(x)$ in series of hyperbolic sines, something like:

$\varphi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sinh(q_nx)$
where $q_n,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is there any way to do it? Would it be too weird?

Comment: As you put it, the $\sinh$ is independent of the sum. Then, this depends on the $a_n$. It is probably not weird. However, if the $q$'s were to depend on $n$, it would probably be quite weird. But what is it that you're asking about? If you don't give the problem, we can't tell you how to do it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that $q$ must depend of $n$.

Comment: If your $q_n$ are integers, setting $x=\ln(t)$ will turn the sum in a Laurent series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fourier series expansion works because $\sin(nx),\cos(nx)$ are an orthonormal basis (after normalizing). You will need to massage things a bit, in order to turn $\sinh(nx),\cosh(nx)$ into an orthonormal basis. For instance, if you are trying to approximate a function on $[0,1]$, you will need your expansion to satisfy
$$
\int_0^1 \sinh(nx)\sinh(mx)=0
$$
when $n\not=m$. This is not literally true, so you could use a procedure like Gram-Schmidt to find a linear combination of these functions that form an orthonormal set.